Android Compose Preview Screenshot Testing Fails due to Could not load font
I just started exploring android compose preview screenshot testing.
In my first attempting running the tests via ./gradlew updateDebugScreenshotTest I got the following error
Cannot update reference images. Rendering failed

The stacktrace suggests
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load font
java.lang.IllegalStateException: layout state is not idle before measure starts

Any idea what could be the issue? I'm using custom fonts and they are in otf format.

I have the exact same problem. Have you found a solution in the end?

it's fixed in alpha version 7. Update your library
